# Silverlight Cross Domain Problem

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain

The problem I'm having is that I have a Silverlight app hosted in an ASP.NET app which is making web service calls to 2 web services in the ASP.NET

Locally this works fine, it is accessing the policy files at http://localhost:1982/crossdomain.xml
Set up on the remote server though it is still looking for the policy at this location, the service references have been updated to reflect there location on the server.
http://webserver/JobWatchService.svc would be the service location but it's still looking for the policy at 
http://localhost:1982/crossdomain.xml

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you used the Visual Studio 'Add Service Reference' function and have created a ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file that is being compiled into your Silverlight XAP. Start by checking that the address attribute of the endpoint node in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig is pointing to `http://webserver/JobWatchService.svc`. It sounds like it is still pointing to your development URL.

Comment: I think it may have been the browser caching the XAP file, I worked around it then noticed in the HTTP tracking it was caching so I come back to it today and removed the cache and it was fine.